# Estrcuturas de contro repetitivas en js

Tags: javascript

necesito resolver este ejercicio para la facultad y no estoy pudiendo. Alguien me podría ayudar?

La letra dice: "Ingresar dos números y al presionar un botón mostrar todos los números entre esos dos números (inclusive). Contemplar el caso que los números se ingresen invertidos (primero el mayor y después el menor)"

- Esto fue lo que yo hice:

```js
function Ejercicio8() {
    let resultado = 0;
    let numero1 = Number(document.querySelector("#txtNumero8").value);
    let numero2 = Number(document.querySelector("txtNumero8A").value);
    while (i <= numero2) {
        if (numero1 > numero2) {
            document.querySelector("#pResultado8").innerHTML += resultado + " ";
        }
        i--
    }
}
```

Gracias!

Comment: Bueno.. tenes un intento.. pero no resuelve nada obviamente.. podrias explicarnos linea por linea que trataste de hacer?

Comment: Sinceramente intente algo que abia iba a ser fallido, no se como hacer para ver los valores entre los dos números insertados

Comment: si en lugar de un while usas un for que vaya desde i= numero1 a numero2 e imprima el valor de i... no lo estas haciendo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te contestaron ya pero te paso mi version por si te sirve:

```
const val1 = document.getElementById("val1")
const val2 = document.getElementById("val2")
const result = document.getElementById("result")

document.getElementById("button").onclick = () =>{
  if(isNaN(val1.value) || isNaN(val2.value)){
    alert("los valores no son validos")
  } else {
    let res1 = parseInt(val1.value)
    let res2 = parseInt(val2.value)
    alert("son correctos")
    if(res1<res2) for(let i=res1;i<=res2;i++) result.textContent += `${i}, `
    else if(res2<res1) for(let h=res2;h<=res1;h++) result.textContent += `${h}, ` 
    else alert("los numeros son iguales")
  }
  console.log(result)
}
```

solo hago alguna que otra validacion mas, agrego el evento onclick a un boton para que muestre los resultados en un div, y siempre se ejecuta del numero menor al mayor da igual cual de los 2 sea, pero eso lo ajustas segun lo que vos necesites modificando. Pero la respuesta de arriba esta bien.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con esto:

```js
function Ejercicio8() {
  let resultado = 0;
  let numero1 = Number(document.querySelector("#txtNumero8").value);
  let numero2 = Number(document.querySelector("#txtNumero8A").value);
  if (numero1 < numero2) {
    var mayor = numero2
    var menor = numero1
  } else {
    var mayor = numero1
    var menor = numero2
  }
  for (let i = menor; i <= mayor; i++) {
    document.querySelector("#pResultado8").innerHTML += i + " ";
  }
}

Ejercicio8()
```

```html
<input id="txtNumero8" value="100">
<input id="txtNumero8A" value="25">
<p id="pResultado8">

</p>
```

### Cambios realizados:

1. Agregar la `#` a `txtNumero8A` en el **querySelector**.
2. Localizar que número es mayor y cual es menor y asignarlo a las variables **mayor** y **menor**
3. Ejecutar un bucle **for** que recorra todos los números comprendidos entre el menor y el mayor y muestre los resultados

A menos que los quieras mostrar en modo invertido, que podría ser así:

```js
function Ejercicio8() {
  let resultado = 0;
  let numero1 = Number(document.querySelector("#txtNumero8").value);
  let numero2 = Number(document.querySelector("#txtNumero8A").value);
  if (numero1 < numero2) {
    for (let i = numero1; i <= numero2; i++) {
      document.querySelector("#pResultado8").innerHTML += i + " ";
    }
  } else {
    for (let i = numero1; i >= numero2; i--) {
      document.querySelector("#pResultado8").innerHTML += i + " ";
    }
  }
}
Ejercicio8()
```

```html
<input id="txtNumero8" value="103">
<input id="txtNumero8A" value="31">
<p id="pResultado8">

</p>
```

Comment: Crack! Gracias!

Comment: He agregado una posible variante a mi respuesta, pues no me queda claro que debe ocurrir cuando el primero es mayor que el segundo (por si quieren que los números se muestren en forma decreciente)

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo Master, ambas funcionan. Te agradezco